# How to proxy a docker compose container?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I'm setting up Atlassian Crowd using Docker. I'm using docker compose to run Crowd from this github repository https://github.com/teamatldocker/crowd

crowd is running on port 8095, now I need to make it available on port 80. I tried with nginx, there are many docker image out there but I didn't have any success.

What is the easiest and best way to have port 8095 proxied to port 80?

Thank you.

Comment: You could try and update the docker-compose.yml to bind to port 80 on the host in the `crowd` sections `ports`  definition?

Comment: But then I need to install certificates and make it run via https. I think the best way is using nginx as proxy no?

Comment: Why are you asking about using port 80 if you want to use HTTPS (which would normally be 443)? Do you use https:// to access this service? The docs your provided a link to seem to suggest by default it isn't using HTTPS too, so not sure where you're getting the idea that this change would require certificates.